# How to redirect to post detail page after creating the blog post in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, javascript

I have created the SharePoint blog post page.After publishing the post,I need to redirect the SharePoint page to published post detail page.it should not redirect to previous page.for using javascript how to handle this?
Suggest an idea to do this redirection using javascript.

Comment: I think you can maybe use the ``source=`` parameter that you provide in the URL. Has been discussed before here on SO (StackOverflow)